# get datum jQuery AJAX from WebAPI return error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

This is my WebApi action method:

```
public List<MemberViewModel> Get(int org)
{
   return DataAccess.Member.GetMembers(org);
}
```

And, This is the jQuery Ajax calling method:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:800/api/Members?org=10",
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (results) {
       alert('worked');
   }
});
```

when I check "Net" tab in firebug, can see the request with result as XML but there is "405 Method Not Allowed" error in status, so that success method will not call.

I removed the "contentType" property from above js code, it works well but the result of the request is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your web application that consumes web API in a port other than 800, the request becomes a cross-origin request. You can use CORS to get around. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Comment: thanks, I cant use CORS, 'cause the client side will run on Phonegap, Any other option to use call ajax cross domain?

Comment: You can try JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Web API does not have an out-of-box media formatter for JSONP, last time I looked at. But it is easy to write one.